# Add custom CSS only for a specific sphinx document

Tags: css, python-sphinx

Is there any way to include a CSS stylesheet only for a certain document in Sphinx?

I am trying to use the autonumbering advice from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212848/is-it-possible-to-make-automatic-section-header-numbering-in-rest-start-at-subse). But as I want to create a bigger documentation I only need numbering for certain documents. 
Therefore I would like to include the presented CSS file only in specific rst files. Is this possible / does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could indent the topic under the cssclass directive:

```
.. cssclass:: customclass

   topic content
```

then define that class in css.  It will only apply to that content.